# Is it ok to store DOM refs into state hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code :

**Groups.js**

```
const Groups = ({ groups }) => {
  const [groupFilter, setGroupFilter] = useState(null)
  return <>
    <div ref={node => setGroupFilter(node)}/>
    <h1>My title</h1>
    <DataList
      data={groups}
      renderFilter={filter => groupFilter && createPortal(
        <div>
          {filter}
          <div>Filter 3</div>
        </div>,
        groupFilter
      )}
    />
  </>
}
```

**DataList.js**

```
const DataList = ({ data, renderFilter }) => {
  return <>
    {renderFilter(<>
      <div>Filter 1</div>
      <div>Filter 2</div>
    </>)}
    data.map(element =>
      <div key={element.id}>{element.name}</div>
    )
  </>
}
```

Basically, `DataList` is there to render a bunch of list filters and the data list itself. `renderFilter` tells the component how to render the filters. From within `Groups` I want to use this render function to render the filters outside of the `DataList` using portals.

I first tried using `useRef`, without success, since it doesn't trigger a rerender when set. Is it safe to do it with a state hook like I did ?

Thanks.

Comment: mmm per docs: "Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component.". But I see in your code that the div in already on React, so, I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @JohnnyZabala Well `DataList` is designed to be a generic component. The "normal" behaviour is to render the filters just on top of the data list, inside `DataList`. But it some specific cases like in `Groups`, I need to render the filters outside `DataList`, so I need a way to render them somewhere else and use portals for that.

But my main question is about the combination of `ref` and `useState`.

Comment: Rewarding to your question, I think it is safe, I wouldn't recommend it because is not a standard thing (this is the first time I see someone storing a ref in state), but outside of that it is safe and React won't freak out because of it.

I asked what you were trying to accomplish because I think there is a better way to do it.

Comment: How would you do it ?

Comment: For example I see this would cover all the use cases that you have right now: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vigilant-hoover-tzhq9. But this is not the only solution or the best. You can try to experiment a little bit more and get a design that satisfy this and even future use cases. For example how about changing the order of the default filters? You can accomplish a lot with just components and composition. Good luck :D

Comment: @JohnnyZabala Thanks. The problem with your demo is that in my real code I need data from within `DataList` to render the filters.

Comment: I don't see the problem. The `Filters` component I create is just that, a component, pass the data to it as a prop and let it deal with the rendering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196472/discussion-between-strebler-and-johnny-zabala).